What 35mm photographic color film from 1984 has "B Y I - 41 6" edge marking at top and "1 1A 1B" frame numbering at the bottom?
While scanning old 35mm film negatives I came across one roll of color film negatives from 1984 of which I cannot determine the type.
At the top there's no color edge marking, there's only the following text: "B Y I •" alternating with "41 6":

At the bottom the frame numbering is "K KA KB", "F FA FB", "1 1A 1B", ... "36 36A 36B", "R":


Can you post an image? Just to get a concrete picture of the top edge marking at least. Also, do you know which country the photographer was likely to have purchased the film in? How do you know it's from 1984?

The bottom edge markings are standard frame number markings.  I forget if the A's and B's are for half-frames or Stereo-Realist interleaved stereoscopic cameras.

I added images of the top and bottom edge. The position of the subframe numbering is particular.

From memory of my film days (25 years ago...). Depending on camera (and how much film you pulled when inserting it in the camera)  the actual pictures can be quite offset from the film markings, so instead of a possibly ambiguous position "22" between two frames, you would use a marker more centered on your frame (21B or 22A, for instance) when ordering prints.

The "41" may well refer to the "C-41" film development process. Indeed, it may also refer to the "B-41" film development process. It then makes me wonder if there's any possibility that "6" could refer to the ISO rating.

I doubt you'd see color film with ISO 6 or 3 in 1984.

@davolfman Unless it's something like an internegative film that is used as an intermediary to make a print from a slide. But that kind of a film likely wouldn't have a stated ISO at all.
